# Python MySQLdb response times are extremely different on silmiliar set

Tags: python, mysql

I am designing a crontab job with Python+MySQLdb to extract data from MySQL, generate XML files and get them zipped. Yes, it is an archive task happens at noon everyday.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#encoding: utf-8
from dmconfig import DmConf
#from dmdb import Dmdb
import redis
import MySQLdb
import dawnutils


import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

conf = DmConf().loadConf()

db = MySQLdb.connect(host=conf["DbHost"],user=conf['DbAccount'],passwd=conf['DbPassword'],\
        db=conf['DbName'],charset=conf['DbCharset'])
cache = redis.Redis(host=conf['RedisHost'], port=conf['RedisPort'], 
        db=conf['Redisdbid'], password=conf['RedisPassword'])

#cursor = db.cursor()

def try_reconnect(conn):
    try:
        conn.ping()
    except:
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=conf["DbHost"],user=conf['DbAccount'],passwd=conf['DbPassword'],\
            db=conf['DbName'],charset=conf['DbCharset'])


def zip_task(device, start, stop):
    #cursor = db.cursor()
    format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
    begin = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.strptime(start,format))
    end = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.strptime(stop,format))
    print "%s (%s,%s)"%(device, begin, end)
    sql = "SELECT * from `period` WHERE `snrCode` = \"%s\" AND `time` > \"%s\" AND `time` < \"%s\" ORDER BY `recId` DESC"%(device, begin, end)
    print sql
    cursor = db.cursor()

    try_reconnect(db)
    t1 = time.time()
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
    except MySQLdb.Error,e:
        print "Error %s"%(e)

    print ("SQL takes %f seconds"%(time.time()-t1))

    print ("len of reconds, %d"%len(results))

    #for row in results:
        #print row


def dispatcher(devSet, start, stop):
    print "size of set: %d"%len(devSet)
    print devSet
    for dev in devSet:
        zip_task(dev, start, stop)

def archive_task_queue():
    today = datetime.now()
    oneday = timedelta(days=1)
    yesterday = today - oneday
    format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
    begin = time.strftime(format, yesterday.timetuple())[:8] + '120000'
    end = time.strftime(format, today.timetuple())[:8] + '120000'

    sql = "SELECT * from `logbook` WHERE `login` > \"%s\" AND `login` < \"%s\" AND `logout` > \"%s\" AND `logout` < \"%s\""%(begin, end, begin, end)
    print sql

    cursor = db.cursor()
    reclist = []
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        results = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in results:
            #print row
            reclist.append(row[1])
    except MySQLdb.Error,e:
        print "Error %s"%(e)

    #reclist = [u'A2H300001']

    if len(reclist):
        dispatcher(set(reclist), begin, end)

    db.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    archive_task_queue()
```

In my code, I will query logbook for device activities, and get the active devices set for that day. And query dataset for each device one by one. The issues comes along with the second stage queries. Check out my console after running:

```
SELECT * from `logbook` WHERE `login` > "20160720120000" AND `login` < "20160721                                                                     120000" AND `logout` > "20160720120000" AND `logout` < "20160721120000"
size of set: 4
set([u'B1H700001', u'B1H700002', u'A1E500018', u'A2H300001'])
B1H700001 (2016-07-20 12:00:00,2016-07-21 12:00:00)
SELECT * from `period` WHERE `snrCode` = "B1H700001" AND `time` > "2016-07-20 12                                                                     :00:00" AND `time` < "2016-07-21 12:00:00" ORDER BY `recId` DESC
SQL takes 0.018232 seconds
len of reconds, 597
B1H700002 (2016-07-20 12:00:00,2016-07-21 12:00:00)
SELECT * from `period` WHERE `snrCode` = "B1H700002" AND `time` > "2016-07-20 12                                                                     :00:00" AND `time` < "2016-07-21 12:00:00" ORDER BY `recId` DESC
SQL takes 0.974020 seconds
len of reconds, 4642
A1E500018 (2016-07-20 12:00:00,2016-07-21 12:00:00)
SELECT * from `period` WHERE `snrCode` = "A1E500018" AND `time` > "2016-07-20 12                                                                     :00:00" AND `time` < "2016-07-21 12:00:00" ORDER BY `recId` DESC
SQL takes 0.342373 seconds
len of reconds, 0
A2H300001 (2016-07-20 12:00:00,2016-07-21 12:00:00)
SELECT * from `period` WHERE `snrCode` = "A2H300001" AND `time` > "2016-07-20 12                                                                     :00:00" AND `time` < "2016-07-21 12:00:00" ORDER BY `recId` DESC

SQL takes 68.173677 seconds
len of reconds, 5794
```

Query time is weired. It takes 0.9s for B1H700002 4642 data points, but it takes 68 seconds for A2H300001 5764 datapoints.

Then I narrow down my issue to query sepecific device ID only, which you can find in my previous code. The result is same. It takes 65 seconds for that query.

Any clue?

Comment: `show create table logbook` and `select count(*) from logbook`

Answer (score 0):

I did more labs on this SQL query. At last I found it is related to memory usage of MySQLdb. Although the total dataset may have only 5794 row, if I added LIMIT 5000, the query only takes 0.3 second, otherwise it takes 60+ seconds.

So, as a work-around approach, I use LIMIT and some pagination methotd to query limited rows for each query and append it to previous queries. And the total time is reduced within 1 second.